# How to CREATE TABLE AS adding an identity?

Tags: oracle

In such way I can create table from a table adding a column number:

```
drop table A_TEST
/
CREATE TABLE A_TEST   AS 
    SELECT CAST( null as NUMBER ) as ROW_ID,
    C_CODE,B_CODE
    FROM A
```

However I want to add the column as an identity how to do that ? I tried the below, but throwing an error:

```
CREATE TABLE A_TEST   AS 
    SELECT CAST( null as NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ) as ROW_ID,
     C_CODE,B_CODE
    FROM A
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not create the table using `CTAS` including the `IDENTITY` column.

But, You can simply create a table without an identity column using `CTAS` and then `ALTER` the table to include `IDENTITY` columns as following:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE A_TEST
>     AS
>         SELECT
>             C_CODE,
>             B_CODE
>         FROM
>             A;
>
> ALTER TABLE A_TEST ADD ROW_ID NUMBER
>     GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY;
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Do it in multiple steps: create the table from the other table without data; then alter the table to add the identity column; and finally insert the data.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A ( A_CODE, B_CODE, C_CODE ) AS
SELECT 999, 'BBB', SYSDATE           FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   0, NULL,  DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Create Table**:

Create the table without the `IDENTITY` column and with no rows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A_TEST   AS 
  SELECT C_CODE, B_CODE
  FROM   A
  WHERE  1 = 0;
```

Then alter the table to add the `IDENTITY` column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE A_TEST ADD (
  ROW_ID  NUMBER
          GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
          CONSTRAINT A_TEST__ROW_ID__PK PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Then insert the rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO A_TEST ( C_CODE, B_CODE )
  SELECT C_CODE, B_CODE FROM A;
```

*(Or you can create the table and insert the rows in the first step; and alter the table to add the identity column without a `NOT NULL`/`PRIMARY KEY` constraint in the second step; and, if you want to add a `NOT NULL`/`PRIMARY KEY` constraint afterwards then it must be done in a separate subsequent `ALTER TABLE` statement. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d6ea18104636dc017fcf5c4e8a68a159))*

**Output**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM A_TEST;
```

> ```
> C_CODE              | B_CODE | ROW_ID
> :------------------ | :----- | -----:
> 2019-12-19 09:06:27 | BBB    |      1
> 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | null   |      2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fdd9987c9460ab5c8b1fc6b992d3f247)*